# Maclurin series for $\sin^2(x)$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I am trying to find the maclurin series expansion for $\sin^{2}x$. First I used the half angle identity:

$$\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}=\sin^{2}x$$

Then substituted in the maclurin series for $\cos(2x)$ to get:

$$\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}2^{2n-1}x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

However my book says that the $\frac{1}{2}$ is not supposed to be there may someone share their process, so I may point out were I went wrong.

Comment: What is the $n=0$ term in your series?

Comment: Thanks, I was having difficulty trying to find an error and was a bit worried I did something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $n = 0$ term in the summation is $\dfrac{(-1)^{1}2^{-1}x^{0}}{0!} = -\dfrac{1}{2}$.

This cancels with the $\dfrac{1}{2}$ term outside the summation.

So the final answer is $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}2^{2n-1}x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$.